# Using filter with a discard channel in Spring Integration DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I don't know if this question is about spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl or both, so I just added the 2 tags...

I spend a considerable amount of time today, first doing a simple flow with a filter

```
StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(...)
                    .filter(messagingFilter)
                    .transform(transformer)
                    .handle((m) -> {
                        (...)
                    })
                    .get();
```

The messagingFilter being a very simple implementation of a MessageSelector. So far so good, no much time spent. But then I wanted to log a message in case the MessageSelector returned false, and here is where I got stuck.

After quite some time I ended up with this:

```
StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(...)
                    .filter(messagingFilters, fs -> fs.discardFlow( i -> i.channel(discardChannel()))
                    .transform(transformer)
                    .handle((m) -> {
                        (...)
                    })
                    .get();

(...)

public MessageChannel discardChannel() {
    MessageChannel channel = new MessageChannel(){
        @Override
        public boolean send(Message<?> message) {
            log.warn((String) message.getPayload().get("msg-failure"));
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean send(Message<?> message, long timeout) {
            return this.send(message);
        }
    };
    return channel;
}
```

This is both ugly and verbose, so the question is, what have I done wrong here and how should I have done it in a better, cleaner, more elegant solution?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem that you don't see that `Filter` is a EI Pattern implementation and the maximum it can do is to send discarded message to some channel. It isn't going to log anything because that approach won't be Messaging-based already.

The simplest way you need for your use-case is like:

```
.discardFlow(df -> df
        .handle(message -> log.warn((String) message.getPayload().get("msg-failure")))))
```

That your logic to just log. Some other people might do more complicated logic. So, eventually you'll get to used to with *channel* abstraction between endpoints.

I agree that `new MessageChannel() {}` approach is wrong. The logging indeed should be done in the `MessageHandler` instead. That is the level of the service responsibility. Also don't forget that there is `LoggingHandler`, which via Java DSL can be achieved as:

```
 .filter(messagingFilters, fs -> fs.discardFlow( i -> i.log(message -> (String) message.getPayload().get("msg-failure"))))
```